# Rendering Tag Helper html from a string

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

We have lots of tag helpers and looking to allow other developers to try and create pages through a code editor, where they write some tag helper and upon submitting, we want to render the output. We want to create something like [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default)

Take the minimal example as in the asp.net docs as follows:

```
    public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "a";
        }
    }
```

We have a code editor when the user writes:

```
<email>foo@foo.com<email>
```

I want to execute this tag helper and render HTML string out of it which should be:

```
<a>foo@foo.com</a>
```

Things can get really complex as you can imagine.

Is there a way to render Tag Helper from string that comes from MVC controller?

I tried to render partial views and view components as string. But no luck. I tried using `Html.Raw()` with encoding and decoding but didnt help as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've been following [this project](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight) for awhile but the development seems slow

Comment: how is it related to the question?

Comment: You want to take a string and run it through razor to output html, yes?

Comment: Not possible. Tag helpers have to be present in the actual Razor view. What @Shoe is referencing is a way to programmatically render strings as if they were full Razor views. That might be a potential workaround, but it you'd have to fundamentally change how your project works with views. As far as using standard *.cshtml files goes, this is a non-starter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little basic example on how to accomplish this. Lets assume we already have the email tag helper in place. AspNetCore 2.2

**Startup.cs**

In `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` add this bit of code

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AllowRecompilingViewsOnFileChange = true;
});
```

This allows the view engine to detect file changes and recompile the view. If this is not set any Environment name besides `Development` will not work.

**HomeController.cs**

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
private readonly string _myTemplatePath;

public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    _myTemplatePath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, @"Views\Shared\_MyTemplate.cshtml");
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
    var myTemplateCode = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_myTemplatePath); 

    return View(new MyTemplateViewModel
    {
        TemplateCode = myTemplateCode
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateMyTemplate(MyTemplateViewModel viewModel)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(_myTemplatePath, viewModel.TemplateCode);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}

public IActionResult GetMyTemplate()
{
    return View("_MyTemplate");
}
```

Some simple code to read/write to _MyTemplate.cshtml file which will act as the editable bit of code.

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
<form asp-action="UpdateMyTemplate" method="post">
    <textarea asp-for="TemplateCode" rows="10"></textarea><br />
    <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
</form>

<h2>Output</h2>
<partial name="_MyTemplate" />
```

**Running the code**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will give it a try.

Comment: this can dramatically affect performance, this should be done conditionally